# Organisation developer program update makes apps impossible to install

Tags: ios, certificate, provisioning-profile, iphone-developer-program

I recently updated my organisation developer program so I can use it one more year, but now my apps seem to be impossible to install, I got this famous error :

> app_name can't be installed at this time

I got this problem on the App Store and for Ad Hoc distribution as well.
My certificates and my provisioning profiles are fine.

Did someone have the same issue recently ?
What could it be ?

Thanks in advance for your answers !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found where the problem came from and it is a bit stupid. Actually, someone in my team recently changed our certificate on the Apple member center but didn't add this certificate to our build server.
After adding the certificate to the build server, everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may have changed your app build settings and are likely not building with the enterprise distribution profile.  That error usually means you are building with a regular development provisioning profile and the device's UDID is not in the list.

Verify your app's build settings are set to build using the Enterprise Distribution Profile.

If you do not believe that to be the case, post the Console logs from the device during an install attempt to find the actual error.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer, the source of the problem was more stupid actually, I just edited my question..

Comment: By the way, it would be best to answer your own question than to edit the question to include the answer,  this will allow others to benefit from easily seeing the solution if they are having the same problem.